# Google Play Console InApp billing Warning

Tags: android, google-play-services, billing

Vulnerable classes:

```
com.google.android.gms.internal.cu
com.google.android.gms.internal.ep
```

I updated google InApp billing AIDL file and IAP Helper
but Warning does not disappear anymore, this google play service version 5089000

Also this App Used Google Login PlusClient
I think I need updated google play service library but  Where do I get google play service library?

Comment: I replace existed library to updated google play service library that is version '6171000' After google developer console warning disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Start the SDK Manager in Android Studio (Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager, or simply use the toolbar button). There is a link "Launch standalone SDK Manager" at the bottom. In this window you see every library you have installed. The play services are near the bottom of the list.
There is even a `Google Play Billing Library` available, together with all other Google libraries.